# How to make parent process invoke wait when child exits with parent unblocked in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, signals

Here is an example, waitpid system call will block parent process until child process exits:

```
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("error\n");
        return -1;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("child\n");
        do_sonmething_in_child();
    } else {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("waitpid returned,do something else\n");
        do_something_else();
    }
```

What I want to achieve is parent process won't be blocked, this can be done by using signal, so I changed my code:

```
void handler(int n) {
    printf("handler %d\n", n);
    int status;
    wait(&status);
}
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) {
    printf("error\n");
    return -1;
} else if (pid == 0) {
    printf("child\n");
    do_sonmething_in_child();
} else {
    int status;
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler);
    do_something_else();
}
```

But another problem comes, if child exit before ***signal(SIGCHLD, handler)***, child will be a zombie, we can't expect the child exit after ***signal(SIGCHLD, handler)*** is invoked, so, how to solve my problem?

Comment: Hi Cong, I do not understand when you say "if the child exists, it will be a zombie". How is it? If it closes/dies, how is it marked as a zombie?

Comment: Because his parent have not invoked wait system call, performing a wait allows the system to release the resources associated with the child, if a wait is not performed, then the terminated child remains in a "zombie" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the signal handler before the fork () call.

Comment: Will child process inherit the signal handler this way?I'm trying to avoid this messy situation, so I don't set the signal handler before the fork() call.

Comment: It will but you can always change it in the child process.